# Вытащить дженерик аргумент за пределы метода C#

Tags: c#, generics

Имеется класс:

```
public class CFPQParserGenerator {

    public IParser<TValue> CreateParser<TValue>(IValuationSemiring<TValue> semiring)
            => AtomEngineFactory.Create(semiring).Accept(new CreateRequest<TValue> ());


    private class CreateRequest<TValue> : IAtomEngineVisitor<TValue, IParser<TValue>>
    {

         public IParser<TValue> Visit<TAtom>(IAtomEngine<TValue, TAtom> engine)
         {
              // some actions
         }
    }

}
```

Запускается метод CreateParser, методу Accept передается объект CreateRequest. Дальше внутри Accept происходит вызов метода Visit.

Вопрос в том как мне в класс CFPQParserGenerator передать значение engine? У меня ведь нет знаний об TAtom. Я хочу engine вытащить за пределы CreateRequest.

Comment: какое определение у `AtomEngineFactory.Create`?